# pandas if else only on specific rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe as below. I want to apply below condition

Only for row where A =2, update the column 'C', 'D' TO -99.

I have a function like below which updates the value of C and D to -99.

```
def func(df):
    for col in df.columns:
        if ("C" in col) or ("D" in col):
            df.loc[:,col] = -99
```

Now i just want to call that function, if A =2. I tried the below code but it updates all the rows of C and D to -99

```
import pandas as pd
import math
import sys
import re
data=[[0,1,0,0, 0],
      [1,2,0,0,0],
      [2,0,0,0,0],
      [2,4,0,0,0],
      [1,8,0,0,0],
      [3,2, 0,0,0]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['A','B','C', 'D','E'])
df
def func(df):
    for col in df.columns:
        if ("C" in col) or ("D" in col):
            df.loc[:,col] = -99

if (df['A'] == 2).any():
    func(df)
    print(df)
```

My expected output:

```
   A  B   C   D  E
0  0  1  0   0  0
1  1  2  0   0  0
2  2  0 -99 -99  0
3  2  4 -99 -99  0
4  1  8  0   0  0
5  3  2  0   0  0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by filtering:

```
df.loc[df['A'] == 2, ['C', 'D']] = -99
```

Here the first item of the filtering filters the rows, and we filter these such that we only select rows where the value for the column of `'A'` is `2`. We filter the columns by a list of names (`C` and `D`). We then assign `-99` to these items.

For the given sample data, we obtain:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['A','B','C', 'D','E'])
>>> df
   A  B  C  D  E
0  0  1  0  0  0
1  1  2  0  0  0
2  2  0  0  0  0
3  2  4  0  0  0
4  1  8  0  0  0
5  3  2  0  0  0
>>> df.loc[df['A'] == 2, ['C', 'D']] = -99
>>> df
   A  B   C   D  E
0  0  1   0   0  0
1  1  2   0   0  0
2  2  0 -99 -99  0
3  2  4 -99 -99  0
4  1  8   0   0  0
5  3  2   0   0  0
```

Comment: There is an update to my question. I already have a function which does the update. I just want to call that function based on the condition

Comment: @Shanoo: I would strongly advice *not* to iterate. Especially since that would make pandas work very slow. Pandas is optimized to process data in bulk. The condition here can be placed as first indexer, see `df['A'] == 2`.

Comment: But in my case, i want to call the function if the condition is true

Comment: @Shanoo: but you do not even call the function when the condition is true. The `.any()` will look if there is at least one row that has as value for the `'A'` column `2`. Then it will pass the *entire* dataframe to the function.

Comment: I understand that but is there any way I could just call the function if condition is true